# Merging videos with AVMutableComposition

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

[image]

I am trying to merge two videos together using AVMutableComposition

After scaling the video's i am not finding a way to crop the video or get rid of the part of the video that is marked red.
I tried using setCropRect but to no use. 
Scaling and translation is working fine but i am stuck at cropping.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AVVideoCompositing . In video composition there is a property custom compositor . There you can get frame by frame buffer of the videos. And the interesting thing is that you can add multiple videos and  for a single time you can get the video frames by track id . Then you can convert the frame buffer into CIImage or Can do in GPU like metal or gpuimage. Here you can draw the frame in the context , You can do anything with the frame buffer like if you use ciimage you can crop it by CICropFilter etc.

Links:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideocompositing?language=objc https://github.com/ElfSundae/AVDemo/tree/master/AVCustomEdit